# `ContentRendered` versus `Loaded`

Tags: wpf

I used to put visible initializations in the constructor after the call to `InitializeComponent`, although I have noticed that examples on the web are not consistent about this: some people initialize before the call to `InitializeComponent`. I recently noticed that even if such initializations are in the `ContentRendered` event, they still appear in time, even though the [Windows Lifetime Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748948.aspx#Window_Lifetime_Events) documentation shows that `ContentRendered` is rather late. In fact, the name implies it is too late: `Content Rendered` is in the past tense. That the following code has the intended behavior suggests that the content has not been truly and completely rendered by the time of the event, and that `ContentRendered` happens earlier than the name suggests. If it's fairly early then this raises the question of why we would ever need to use `Loaded`, which is also earlier than the complete rendering?

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ContentRenderedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Content = "This is Label1";
            TextBox1.Text = "hello";
        }
    }

<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
               ContentRendered="ContentRenderedEvent">
    <StackPanel>
        <Label x:Name="Label1" Margin="5" 
             Width="100" Height="30">not initialized</Label>
        <TextBox Margin="5" x:Name="TextBox1" Width="60" Height="30"></TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though `ContentRendered` is in fact too late, the properties you are initializing (`Label.Content`, `TextBox.Text`) are `DependencyProperties`. The framework traks whenever they are changed, and this forces UI to be updated. That (plus bindings) is the whole point of having them at all, instead of simple auto-props with trivial get/set pair.

So, when you assign them in `ContentRendered` then:

- UI is constructed
- UI is measured and layed out
- UI is rendered without them being initialized yet
- you are setting these properties (almost immediatelly after rendering)
- UI gets updated values (almost immediatelly after you set them)
- UI is measured and layed out, again
- you see on UI that "they are there as if it's ok"

comparing to when you do that in Loaded:

- UI is constructed
- you are setting these properties
- UI is measured and layed out
- you see on UI that "they are there as if it's ok"

That's a rough sketch but you should see the obvious difference. The key points are:

- you probably simply didn't managed to see the very fast update on screen, in fact, WPF could double-buffer, v-sync, or something like that that and the intermediate redering might simply be not visible at all. You may try to capture some state of the View at `ContentRendered` event - you can for example save the current View as PNG programmatically to be able to see the exact intermediate state
- remember that DependencyProperties are **smart**. Go to their docs (i.e. `TextBox.Text`) - and check their flags. If you see something like `AffectsRender/Measure/Arrange`. then changing them will trigger almost immediate update/repaint. All three flags are important. "Content"-like properties (Text, Content, DataSource, Items, ...) are almost always marked with `AffectsMeasure` since changing the content usually should force not only painting, but also full layout cycle to be remade **on every change to values**. "style"-type props (Foreground, Background, Fill, Brush, ..) usually have just `AffectsRender` since repaint is enough, and layout can be the same. And so on. [More on that i.e. here on excellent Dr.WPF blog](http://drwpf.com/blog/2010/05/08/metadata-options-for-silverlight/). Although it's about Silverlight, basics still apply.